# Flutter_InAppWebView onReceivedHttpAuthRequest Not Authenticating user with older Android 7.0

Tags: flutter, dart, sharepoint, flutter-inappwebview

I am using the `InAppWebView` from the `flutter_inappwebview ^5.6.0+2` package in my Flutter app for users to access an internal Sharepoint site that requires authentication. I added the following code to handle the HTTP Authentication:

```
onReceivedHttpAuthRequest: (controller, challenge) async {
    print('received auth request');

    return new HttpAuthResponse(
        username: "companydomain\\$username",
        password: "password",
        action: HttpAuthResponseAction.PROCEED,
        permanentPersistence: true,
    );
```

On iOS and newer version of Android (Android 11 and above), this works without issue and the authentication with the site works. However, when I run this on an Android 7.0 device, the authentication did not happen successfully and I can see 'received auth request' being printed many times (about 100+) to the console:

```
W/chromium(20503): [WARNING:render_frame_host_impl.cc(2728)] OnDidStopLoading was called twice.
52
I/flutter (20503): received auth request
W/FA      (20503): Ignoring call to log screen view event with duplicate parameters.
2
I/flutter (20503): received auth request
E/BufferItemConsumer(20503): [ImageReader-1080x1812f1m3-20503-0] Failed to release buffer: Unknown error -1 (1)
E/ConnectivityManager.CallbackHandler(20503): callback not found for RELEASED message
```

How could I handle the auth request for older Android devices?